# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsCleanupResourcesDebug'. > Crashlytics Developer Tools error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

I have this mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends RoboFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Crashlytics.start(this);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity_with_Fragment.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

this is my gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.2'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stopcall.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

When I run project build I get this compilation error:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsCleanupResourcesDebug'.
> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: This doesn't seem like enough info to debug the problem.  Can you try compiling from the command line with verbose output (gradle -info compileDebugSources).  Post the error messages from that output.

Comment: Have you added your API key to the app manifest? I had this same error and that was my issue.

Comment: I also got the issue and resolved it by putting string directly in meta tag without defining the api key into string resources. e.g.
Replace

    **<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="@string/string_res_name_of_your_api_key" />**
to

   **<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="your_api_key_string" />**

Comment: I have a solution, fix of this problem:
Please get my answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40949152/3819836

Comment: I fixed this issue by following [Hassan Jamil's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40949152/3819836). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 67):

You need to add your API Key to the Android Manifest:

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
        android:value="your key here" />
</application>
```

Comment: i only want to use fabric for twitter login. Why should i use crashlytics. Still i got same issue. Can you please give solution to that?

Comment: This is automatically added when using the plugin. And I am still receiving this error. I am not sure that this is the solution.

Comment: I was assigning string resource (because of different live and debug keys) to `value`. It appears that it doesn't work. Sad.

Answer (score 36):

**This method solved my problem:**

Remove or Comment this line (build.gradle):

```
  // apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

or if you have an ApiKey, define fabric ApiKey (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="yourApiKey012356465654" />
```

Comment: Run time error solved. But getting a toast "Unable to complete action" when login with Twitter. Any suggestion please?

Comment: you saved my life

Comment: @VinilChandran maybe u must obtain fabric key (https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-can-i-get-apikey/26162/2) and put it to AndroidManifest.xml ???

Answer (score 25):

If you only want to compose a tweet with the SDK you can remove the line

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

And the gradle build will work correctly

Answer (score 18):

I also got the issue and resolved it by putting string directly in meta tag without defining the api key into string resources. 
**e.g.
Replace**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="@string/string_res_name_of_your_api_key" />
```

**to**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="your_api_key_string" />
```

Comment: Android Studio (2.3 Canary 2, Build #AI-162.3508619, built on November 18, 2016) error here I think! This solution worked for me

Comment: I still ran into this issue with Android Studio 2.3.3. This solution worked.
The issue didn't occur as long as my project consisted of one module. It occurred when I added the crashlytics dependency in a library project and applied the plugin in the app module.

Comment: The issue resolved in our case with this answer. I did'nt understand though why ?

Answer (score 8):

*When you follow the steps for adding an application in your Crashlytics dashboard, they have mentioned a step to add the api key. In my case I was getting the same error when I would try to fetch the key from the strings.xml file. The problem was that crashlytics plugin uses a runtime api key insertion method and hence the build fails as it is not able to get the key from the strings file.*

**I tried below step:**

1. Add a manifest placeholder in your build.gradle's defaultConfig:

```json
    defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [ api_key_crashlytics:"xxxx__your_api_key"]}
```

2. In your AndroidManifest.xml add below code inside your application tag:

```xml
<meta-data
      android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
      android:value="${api_key_crashlytics}" />
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you added

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the end of your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Fabric Plugin which is already installed and update the Crashlytics, your problem gets solved

Comment: Error is coming because you have not updated the Crashlytics , once you update it,its get solved

Answer (score 1):

I faced with this issue for sometimes, although I already had api key in manifest. Then I try assemble release apk before try to assemble to upload to Fabric. So let execute:

```
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

then

```
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [distribution with Gradle](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html) you may have checked some properties like

> ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath=”path/to/release_notes.txt”

In our case we didn't have this file and the task crashed. To see the problem, go to Gradle console and check logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of your solution suggests under that question and others. But all of them did not solve my problem. I solved my problem. My solution may solve your problem. I created empty res folder under main folder. project->src->main->res

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the ApiKey is not correct just check it out. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your key may have been entered on the wrong Android Manifest

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="yourApiKey" />          //You must have 40 words
```

You can get the code after registering and entering the project

https://fabric.io/home