# Unable to build Android app FabricGenerateResourcesDebug

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to integrate twitter's sdk with my app. I'm following [this guide](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate).

Unfortunately, when I try to build my project, I keep receiving this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
>   Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

Unfortunately because I don't have 10 reputation, I can't post my build.gradle file because it has links in it. Just trust the fact that it looks just like the build.gradle example in the top link provided.

Is there something that I'm missing that I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem should be caused due to that you did not create a “crashlytics.properties” file which is required to contain API Key and Build Secret in your app directory.

The solution is quite simple that you don't even have to manually setup anything on your original project. Just following this link:

https://fabric.io/settings/organizations

It will lead you to the Fabric official website, which helps you to download and install Fabric plugins into your IDE (Android Studio, IntelliJ or Eclipse). This might be a new magical method to integrate twitter's SDK within your app, it will automatically configure your project. You will see the magic when you get there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey I am also facing same issue. I added the plugin and followed the steps. I haven't created any properties file. I wonder why crashlytics is required. I only want twitter sharing feature. May be fabric is using the crashlytics. Is there any option to disable the requirement of crashlytics ?

Comment: @HardikTrivedi You should try to remove "apply plugin: 'io.fabric'"

Comment: @bina thanks. I didn't need that line to just be able to post a twitter status from app and that solved my build error.

Comment: That's the link I started with, and why I'm here trying to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: I've used Fabric on several projects and on every single one the IDE plugin has caused more problems than it solved. eg right now Android Studio's IDE plugins dialog is broken, I cannot install the Fabric IDE plugin, but the Fabric web site mandates plugin use to even create an API key, making use of Fabric impossible. I hate this Fabric plugin with great passion. It is not "magic", it's a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

The fix I found is that I did not place the meta-data tag with the API Key INSIDE the application tag in the androidmanifest.xml.