# Error in build gradle when integrating twitter sdk

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am developing an app that allows connection with twitter for sharing contents purposes. I have added Fabric plugins and the codings in build gradle but i could not execute the program. It shows error in build gradle. When i change the API setting the app crashes. I tried referring to examples of solutions but could not solve it. Can anyone guide me on solving this problem. My build.gradle are as follow.

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
 }

 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
 }
```

Error log :

> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugTestSources, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugTestSources]
>   :app:clean
>   :app:clean UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preBuild
>   :app:preDebugBuild
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library
>   :app:prepareComDigitsSdkAndroidDigits180Library
>   :app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library
>   :app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetComposer090Library
>   :app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetUi150Library
>   :app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitter180Library
>   :app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitterCore150Library
>   :app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric135Library
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   :pp:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_clear_normal.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/mcm/AndroidStudioProjects/App/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   :app:processDebugManifest
>   :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
>   ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
>   Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
>   Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processApiKey(DeveloperTools.java:326)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:466)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgs(DeveloperTools.java:299)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.main(DeveloperTools.java:270)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:313)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.this$2$callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:368)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$_pluginGenerateResources_closure3.doCall(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:112)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:548)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:529)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$1.execute(TaskMutator.java:77)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$1.execute(TaskMutator.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>       at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
>   Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 6.02 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Why don't you use latest v4 and v7 library ?

Comment: yes i have tried using version 23.0.1 and i have updated the sdk manager. there is no error in error log when i made this changes but i cant run my app in device. it stops after executing splash screen. @Soham

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891325/unable-to-build-android-app-fabricgenerateresourcesdebug/28904536#28904536)

Comment: @Soham yes i have tried that. i have downloaded the twitter kit and installed in plugins. the error is still there.

Comment: Hi @marian, I found the exact error as above, have you found the solution? thanks