# Crashlytics Developer Tools error

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have the following code in build.gradle in Android Studio:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.4'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39817088/2686502

Comment: I am facing the same issue. They all say add API key, but in the new Firebase Crashlytics. There is no need to add API key in the meta. Even if I do I get the same error.