# Error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException .. Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'. Crashlytics Developer Tools error

Tags: android, android-studio

### Getting the error on building the android studio. How to resolve this:

**ERROR:**

```
Error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 148; columnNumber: 88; The prefix "tools" for element "tools:validation" is not bound.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
```

---

**GradleFile:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "PackageName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 20
        versionName "20.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
}


dependencies {
    //Dependencies 
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**`EDIT:` I have Added the crashlytics key in manifest**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="bddb9792335804f5fee7" />
```

Comment: Read https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#customize-your-build-gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try this [one](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/34072648) . You can also solve it with the Fabric plugin in Android Studio.

Hope this works !

Comment: Check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255757/errorgradle-execution-failed-for-task-appcrashlyticscleanupresourcesdebug . Maybe one of the solutions solve your problem

Comment: Try commenting this line : apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

Comment: Commenting the line `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` 
won't resolve the error. I tried this

Comment: Try cleaning your project once and then try these solutions.It helps sometimes :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169030/discussion-between-shubham-srivastava-and-devrath).

Answer (score 0):

Issue for never the Crashlytics Problem
SAX error got resolved by Removing some other tags related to Deep linking :)